# Session doesn't seem supported by a browser

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I have a situation where a part of some code depends on fetching a value out of the ASP.NET *Session State*. This works fine in all major browsers, however I one client that, for whatever reason, uses the **AOL** web browser, and it seems to be incapable of understanding this logic.

Every time there is a call to the session state in the code, even on the server side, the page throws an exception for them. This is easily remedied by simply having them use another browser - but I am wondering, is there a way to get around this sort of behavior?

Comment: What type of session are you using? By default the session is stored in a cookie. Maybe this aol browser is blocking all type of cookies? If this is the case, maybe he can relax a little this feature or you can change the persistance to sql

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't realize that. Yes, it is just cookie blocking. I feel ...so stupid.

Answer (score 2):

By default the session is stored in a cookie. Maybe this aol browser is blocking all type of cookies? If this is the case, maybe he can relax a little this feature or you can change the persistance to sql.

Reposted just to mark the question closed and answered

Comment: " or you can change the persistance to sql." ... or configure the application to use cookieless sessions

Comment: Yup, but that would produce horrible url